# Jenkins connect to Windows 10 agent

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins master on a Linux machine and I would like it to be able to connect to a Windows 10 agent, how do I do that?

I can't find much in the official documentation about agents in general, and as for searching the web, the results show how to do it using JNLP, which only works on Java 8 and not on 11, and I don't want to downgrade from 11 to 8.

I've been able to set up Linux agents, to which I connect using ssh ([like this](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/222978868-How-to-Connect-to-Remote-SSH-Slaves)), but the same process doesn't seem to work for the Windows agent.

I am at wits' end here, do you know or have any up-to-date resources on connecting to Windows agents? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the following link: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+agent+machines+on+Windows
I advise you to configure a node on the master ( manage --> manage nodes ) and set the `launch method` to  `launch agent by connecting it to the master`. After that you have three methods to connect the Windows agent to Jenkins master, the easiest way will be to lanch it from a browser.
[image]
This should work enven with jdk 11.

Comment: Link seems to be about Windows master to Windows agent. Would it work for Linux master to Windows agent as well ?

Comment: that's what i'm using for a Jenkins Master on Linux <--> Jenkins agent on Windows. if you encounter a specific error please share the details with jenkins version.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a Jenkins windows slave to a Jenkins master running on Linux not too long ago and wrote the steps I've taken for future use.

Here's what needs to be done:

Jenkins service on the windows slave needs to be started with a dedicated user rather than local system account.

Then I had some problems when I tried connecting from the master jenkins to this windows-jenkins-slave of "Access denied" - when the master tried to start the local service.

In order to avoid "Access denied" errors when the master tries connecting to windows slave, follow these steps:

- Create a dedicated user for jenkins which is a member of the local administrative group on the windows-jenkins-slave.
- Allow the local administrator group full control over the following registry values:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID{72C24DD5-D70A-438B-8A42-98424B88AFB8}
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{76A64158-CB41-11D1-8B02-00600806D9B6}

And then reboot the windows agent to apply the changes to the registry.

Then, Configure the node in master Jenkins like so:
[image]

this jenkins user is the local user I've created.

- Add this local jenkins user to the jenkins service as the log on user.